# How to debug an app on Pixel 2

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am attempting to connect `Android Studio` to my Pixel 2 android phone.

**Android Studio version :-**

```
Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.11.6
```

My Pixel 2 has `Android 8.1.0` Build Number OPM1.171019.011

When I connect this device to Android Studio I get the following Event Log output:-

```
21/12/2017
07:54   Adb connection Error:EOF
07:54   Connection attempts: 1
07:54   Connection attempts: 2
07:54   Connection attempts: 3
07:54   Connection attempts: 4
07:55   Connection attempts: 5
07:55   Connection attempts: 6
07:55   Connection attempts: 7
07:55   Connection attempts: 8
07:55   Connection attempts: 9
07:55   Connection attempts: 10
07:55   Connection attempts: 11
07:55   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
07:55   ADB server didn't ACK
07:55   Full server startup log: /var/folders/jt/0vbjn9c967jbxl0d9p_x6z78783df6/T//adb.243381702.log
07:55   Server had pid: 1737
07:55   --- adb starting (pid 1737) ---
07:55   adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
07:55   adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 main.cpp:57] Version 27.0.0-4455170
07:55   adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 main.cpp:57] Installed as /Users/proutylf/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
07:55   adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 main.cpp:57] 
07:55   adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
07:55   adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/Users/proutylf/.android/adbkey'...
07:55   adb F 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83701 transport_usb.cpp:37] Check failed: usb_packet_size < 4096ULL (usb_packet_size=5120, 4096ULL=4096) 
07:55   * failed to start daemon
07:55   error: cannot connect to daemon
07:55   '/Users/proutylf/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
07:55   adb restart attempts: 1
07:55   Connection attempts: 12
07:55   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
07:55   ADB server didn't ACK
07:55   Full server startup log: /var/folders/jt/0vbjn9c967jbxl0d9p_x6z78783df6/T//adb.243381702.log
07:55   Server had pid: 1739
```

The log file contents are as follows:-

```
--- adb starting (pid 1727) ---
adb I 12-21 07:54:19  1727 81771 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 12-21 07:54:19  1727 81771 main.cpp:57] Version 27.0.0-4455170
adb I 12-21 07:54:19  1727 81771 main.cpp:57] Installed as /Users/proutylf/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 12-21 07:54:19  1727 81771 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 12-21 07:54:19  1727 81771 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 12-21 07:54:19  1727 81771 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/Users/proutylf/.android/adbkey'...
adb F 12-21 07:54:56  1727 83260 transport_usb.cpp:37] Check failed: usb_packet_size < 4096ULL (usb_packet_size=5120, 4096ULL=4096) 
--- adb starting (pid 1737) ---
adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 main.cpp:57] Version 27.0.0-4455170
adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 main.cpp:57] Installed as /Users/proutylf/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83688 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/Users/proutylf/.android/adbkey'...
adb F 12-21 07:55:07  1737 83701 transport_usb.cpp:37] Check failed: usb_packet_size < 4096ULL (usb_packet_size=5120, 4096ULL=4096) 
--- adb starting (pid 1739) ---
adb I 12-21 07:55:08  1739 83918 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 12-21 07:55:08  1739 83918 main.cpp:57] Version 27.0.0-4455170
adb I 12-21 07:55:08  1739 83918 main.cpp:57] Installed as /Users/proutylf/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 12-21 07:55:08  1739 83918 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 12-21 07:55:08  1739 83918 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 12-21 07:55:08  1739 83918 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/Users/proutylf/.android/adbkey'...
adb F 12-21 07:55:08  1739 83951 transport_usb.cpp:37] Check failed: usb_packet_size < 4096ULL (usb_packet_size=5120, 4096ULL=4096)
```

I have `buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'` installed.

All my other Android devices connect ok to Android Studio including my Pixel XL which has identical Android version and build number as my Pixel 2.

How can I resolve this adb connection issue?

If it is of any help, my adb version is reporting as

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 27.0.0-4455170
Installed as /Users/proutylf/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

Comment: why downvote this question? please leave a comment next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What platform tools version are you on? I had the exact same error on my pixel 2. I had platform tools version 27.0.0. I downloaded a previous version and that worked for me. I found the answer here: [Android Studio - ADB start server fails, adbkey check fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665475/android-studio-adb-start-server-fails-adbkey-check-fails)

Comment: It looks as though t his has been fixed with platform tools 27.0.1